Does TensorFlow or XLA provide a python API to read and parse the dumped MHLO mlir module?
I turned on XLA when running TensorFLow, and in order to further optimize the fused kernels, I added export XLA_FLAGS="--xla_dump_to=/tmp/xla_dump", and got the dumped IRs, including lmhlo.xxx.mlir and other llvm IRs.
Now as I'm trying to further analyze those dumped mlir's, I want to read them as structured MLIR modules, so I need to read and parse it correctly. But I can't find any resources documenting how to do this in pure python, I tried "pymlir" module, but not working well with this TF XLA HLO module, maybe the dumped module has different format.
So does anybody know how to read and parse this dumped mlir?

You can use the MLIR Python bindings to parse the MLIR files being dumped. Here's the general process and you can tweak the actual script as needed.

Clone the LLVM project repository
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git


Create a build directory
cd llvm-project
mkdir build
cd build


Configure the build to include MLIR and enable Python bindings
cmake -G Ninja ../llvm \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="mlir" \
  -DLLVM_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="host" \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_BINDINGS=ON \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON \
  -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3)


Build project
ninja


Add the bindings to your PYTHONPATH to make sure Python can find the MLIR modules
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)/tools/mlir/python_packages/mlir_core


Once the environment is set up, you can parse and analyze MLIR files. Here's a script that will read the MLIR file and iterate through its operations. It starts by initializing the MLIR context, registers the lmhlo dialect (assuming that's what the XLA dump uses), reads the dumped MLIR file, and parses it into a structured module so you can look at its operations.
from mlir import ir

# initialize MLIR context
with ir.Context() as ctx:
    # register lmhlo dialect
    from mlir.dialects import lmhlo
    lmhlo.register_dialect(ctx)

    # read file
    with open('/tmp/xla_dump/lmhlo.xxx.mlir', 'r') as f:
        mlir_module = f.read()

    # parse
    module = ir.Module.parse(mlir_module)

    # loop through operations
    for op in module.body.operations:
        print(op)




Resources

MLIR-HLO GitHub Repository
MLIR Python Bindings Documentation
Building a Compiler with MLIR
MLIR: intermediate representation and compiler framework

